# Fade in and out multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

This is my code for resizing the window and some other elements and in the scroll function. I have a div that appears and disappears in different position of the screen depending on the `x.top` of the window.

The problem on the scroll function when I go to `hidden_div2` the text inside the `<p>` fades in. My problem is when you come back to first div the text fades in and out 6 times. HELP :(

```
var image_position = new Array();
var i = 0;

function imageResize() {
    $('.images').find('img').each( function (){
        var dwidth = $(window).width();
        var dheight = $(window).height();
        
        var imagewidth = $(this).attr('width');
        var imageheight = $(this).attr('height');
        var imageratio = imagewidth / imageheight;
        
        var imagehresize = dwidth;
        var imagevresize = imagehresize * imageratio;
        
        var x = $(this).parent('div').position();
        image_position[i] = x.top;
    
        var boxleft = dwidth / 6;

        i++;
    });
    
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var x = $('.hidden_div').offset();
    var img1 = image_position[2];
    var img2 = image_position[3];
    
    if(x.top > img1){
        $('.hidden_div').css('z-index', '40');
        $('.hidden_div p').fadeOut(2000);
        $('.hidden_div2').css('z-index', '130');
        $('.hidden_div2 p').fadeIn(2000);

    }
    else if(x.top < img1){
        $('.hidden_div').css('z-index', '130');
        $('.hidden_div p').fadeIn(2000);
        $('.hidden_div2').css('z-index', '40');
        $('.hidden_div2 p').fadeOut(2000);
    }

});
```

Comment: there is to much code to remake the effect but this is the important part only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scroll event is generated one or more times as the user scrolls.  It is NOT only generated once for each overall user scroll.  It may be generated many times.  Thus, you are seeing more than one scroll event.

If you want to carry out an action AFTER the user appears to be done with a scrolling operation, then you will have to debounce the scroll event so that you only start your operation after a scroll event occurs and no more scroll events occur for some period of time (often 1-2 seconds).

In your code, that debouncing can be done like this:

```
var scrollTimer;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // if we had a scrollTimer running, stop it
    if (scrollTimer) {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    }
    // set a new scrollTimer
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        scrollTimer = null;
        processScroll();
    }, 1000);   // wait for 1 second of no-scroll events before firing our changes
});

function processScroll() {
    var x = $('.hidden_div').offset();
    var img1 = image_position[2];
    var img2 = image_position[3];

    if(x.top > img1){
        $('.hidden_div').css('z-index', '40');
        $('.hidden_div p').fadeOut(2000);
        $('.hidden_div2').css('z-index', '130');
        $('.hidden_div2 p').fadeIn(2000);

    }
    else if(x.top < img1){
        $('.hidden_div').css('z-index', '130');
        $('.hidden_div p').fadeIn(2000);
        $('.hidden_div2').css('z-index', '40');
        $('.hidden_div2 p').fadeOut(2000);
    }

}
```

If you don't want the debouncing, then perhaps you can just stop the previous animation like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var x = $('.hidden_div').offset();
    var img1 = image_position[2];
    var img2 = image_position[3];

    if(x.top > img1){
        $('.hidden_div').css('z-index', '40');
        $('.hidden_div p').stop(true).fadeOut(2000);
        $('.hidden_div2').css('z-index', '130');
        $('.hidden_div2 p').stop(true).fadeIn(2000);

    }
    else if(x.top < img1){
        $('.hidden_div').css('z-index', '130');
        $('.hidden_div p').stop(true).fadeIn(2000);
        $('.hidden_div2').css('z-index', '40');
        $('.hidden_div2 p').stop(true).fadeOut(2000);
    }

});
```

Comment: the event is basicaly on scroll but it's targeted by links inside div wich takes u to the slide event. The event is only called once when i come back to it. Any ideeas on how can i fix this ?

Comment: @BloodRayneBlood - I added a code example for debouncing the scroll event.

Comment: yeapz tested it and same thing nothing changes, and the fade in needs to be down while the page is scroling

Comment: @BloodRayneBlood - Your question is not entirely clear.  I thought you were saying that the scroll event was getting called 6 times when the user scrolled.  That is the problem I solved.  This will work if properly implemented.  If you have a different problem, you will need to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @BloodRayneBlood - what is a "fade event"?  I've never heard of such a thing.  Your code is processing "scroll events" and it makes `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` function calls inside the scroll event handler.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9218/discussion-between-bloodrayne-blood-and-jfriend00)

Comment: I added another option to my answer (at the end) that uses `.stop(true)` to stop the previous animations so they don't pile up.